# Trying to make add elements of a list together

Tags: python

I have the following code. As you'll notice, the three for loops are identical except the index of the second `customerList` increases by one for each iteration. What I am doing is adding the length of calls to list `hey` when the calls are between the same two people. This method is working, but I need to continue it for about 80 different caller/receiver combinations. Any ideas on the best way to do this?

```
for i in range(0, len(listOfCalls)):
    if listOfCalls[i][1] == customerList[0][1] or listOfCalls[i][1] == customerList[2][1]:
        if listOfCalls[i][2] == customerList[0][1] or listOfCalls[i][2] == customerList[2][1]:
            hey[1] += int(listOfCalls[i][3])  


for i in range(0, len(listOfCalls)):
    if listOfCalls[i][1] == customerList[0][1] or listOfCalls[i][1] == customerList[3][1]:
        if listOfCalls[i][2] == customerList[0][1] or listOfCalls[i][2] == customerList[3][1]:
            hey[2] += int(listOfCalls[i][3])


for i in range(0, len(listOfCalls)):
    if listOfCalls[i][1] == customerList[0][1] or listOfCalls[i][1] == customerList[4][1]:
        if listOfCalls[i][2] == customerList[0][1] or listOfCalls[i][2] == customerList[4][1]:
            hey[3] += int(listOfCalls[i][3])
```

Comment: Why not write a function with your `for` loops and then call it with your new `index`?

Comment: can you give some example data.  what does listOfCalls, customerList and hey look like?  What you trying to get as output?

Comment: listOfCalls is a list of about a thousand phone calls where the 1st element is the caller, the 2nd element the receiver and 3rd the call length

customerList is a list of the 9 different customers with the 1st element being their number

hey is simply an empty list that I am attempting to get the total call length between each caller in

Comment: You are obviously trying to compute some sums. Can you express in natural language what you want to sum up? How are the ~ 80 caller/receiver combinations determined? Is there some rule to pair them up, or do the pairs come from a list?

Comment: The ultimate goal is to output a file where it indicated the length of calls between two numbers from the list regardless of who called who.

therefore the final output will be

2,3,56677

for example with 2 and 3 referencing numbers from the call list and the last number being the call length

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think you want.  I think you're trying to determine the total amount of time two people spent on the phone with one anther, regardless of who called who.  Instead of using the list "hey", you'd be better off making a dictionary "hey" where the key is the tuple (caller1, caller2) in sorted order. So something like this:

```
hey = {}
for call in listOfCalls:
    caller1, caller2, dur = call
    key = tuple(sorted((caller1, caller2)))
    if key in hey:
         hey[key] += int(dur)
    else:
         hey[key] = int(dur)
```

Comment: I never thought to use tuples as a key...
however it says i have too many values to unpack in the 3rd line of this code

Comment: can you posted the first few elements of listOfCalls.  Is it a flat-list or a list of lists?

Comment: I altered it so that caller 1 caller 2 and dur are set equal to the appropriate elements of the list. So now I have a dictionary of what's needed. Thank you!

Comment: follow up question. if i want to assign each caller number to a specific number i.e. 7801234567 =1, 7801236789 =2 and so on, how would i do this using the newly created dictionarry

Comment: where does the specific number come from?  sounds like you are describing a dictionary again.  Make new dict like client_map[1] = <your num>

Comment: each phone number has a preassigned number

Comment: figured it out have it working like I need. Appreciate your time Garrett!